# Swift + Alamofire - Auth and get XML file

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a website that is protected with Username and Password. 
I need to get XML file and then parse it. I tried many solution but none of them worked for me. I am getting this code.

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Encountered unknown tag
>   tabless on line 1) UserInfo=0x1aadf300 {NSDebugDescription=Encountered
>   unknown tag tabless on line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)}

here is my code:

```
 func getTimeStampOfUpdatedTables(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> (){

    let user = "abc"
    let password = "abc"

    let plainString = "\(user):\(password)" as NSString
    let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64String!]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/info.php", encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responsePropertyList { response in
        print(response.result)
        if let error = response.result.error {
            print("Error: \(error)")

            // parsing the data to an array
        } else if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: String]] {

            if array.isEmpty {
                print("No data")

            } else {
                //Do whatever you want to do with the array here
                print("data here!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is given because your API response is in XML not property list format.
you are requesting property list from Alamofire it was unable to find pList format so it was giving error. i tested the code with PList and it worked fine

Here is the Property list format

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Tabless</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Tables</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 3</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 4</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 5</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 6</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 7</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 8</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
            <key>Tables - 9</key>
            <dict>
                <key>test</key>
                <string>test</string>

            </dict>
```

> I HAVE TESTED THE WHOLE THING

```
     let user = "abc"
    let password = "abc"

    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://192.168.0.100/r.php", headers: headers)
        .responsePropertyList { response in

        print(response.result)
        if let error = response.result.error {
            print("Error: \(error)")

            // parsing the data to an array
        } else if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: String]] {

            if array.isEmpty {
                print("No data")

            } else {
                //Do whatever you want to do with the array here
                print("data here!")
            }
        }
    }
```

For parsing XML data, you could consider [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash). The Alamofire request could look like:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(data) // if you want to check XML data in debug window.
            var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
            println(xml["tabless"][0]["TABLE_NAME"].element?.text) 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bello code:-

```
func getTimeStampOfUpdatedTables(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> (){

    let username = "abc"
    let password = "abc"

            let credentialData = "\(username):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance

        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300

        manager.request(.GET, url,parameters: dicsParams, headers: headers).responsePropertyList { response in
        print(response.result)
        if let error = response.result.error {
            print("Error: \(error)")

            // parsing the data to an array
        } else if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: String]] {

            if array.isEmpty {
                print("No data")

            } else {
                //Do whatever you want to do with the array here
                print("data here!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what to do with dicsParams?

Comment: discParam is a parameter dictionary.

Comment: yes but in your provided code there is no such identificator for this dictionary.

Comment: let dicsParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "username" : "abc",
        ]

Comment: parsing parameter look like above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111004/discussion-between-mitul-marsonia-and-pan-mluvci).